# Cannot connect to coral dev board after updating to 4.0: mdt shell does not work

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-coral, mdtool

Recently I updated and flushed the dev board with mendel-enterprise-day-13 according to the coral AI official documentation. After that, when I want to connect from my desktop Ubuntu 19.04 using `mdt shell` or `mdt shell <ip>`, it does not work and gives an error message as follows. [mdt shell does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxbLg.png)

> Connecting to 192.168.101.2 at 192.168.101.2 Key not present on
>   192.168.101.2 -- pushing
>
> It looks like you're trying to connect to a device that isn't connected
>   to your workstation via USB and doesn't have the SSH key this MDT generated.
>   To connect with `mdt shell` you will need to first connect to your device
>   ONLY via USB.
>
> Cowardly refusing to attempt to push a key to a public machine.
>   Connecting to 192.168.101.2 at 192.168.101.2
>   Key not present on 192.168.101.2 -- pushing
>
> It looks like you're trying to connect to a device that isn't connected
>   to your workstation via USB and doesn't have the SSH key this MDT generated.
>   To connect with `mdt shell` you will need to first connect to your device
>   ONLY via USB.
>
> Cowardly refusing to attempt to push a key to a public machine.

Even though my coral board is connected via both USB C and USB A, it cannot see USB as connected. I ran nmtui from the board terminal to see all active connections and it shows that the board is connected only for USB0 and USB1 and no internet (please see the results below):
[active connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROMSI.png)

I also would like to share one strange thing that I found after running `dmesg | grep ttyUSB`. It shows several failures and disconnections.
[usb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CANAX.png)

```
[  371.021431] usb 3-1.4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  371.023282] usb 3-1.4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 3326.853419] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x12 status: -19
[ 3326.853423] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x0 status: -19
[ 3326.853563] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 3326.853728] cp210x ttyUSB1: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[ 3332.837337] usb 3-1.4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 3332.839815] usb 3-1.4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 4001.567889] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x12 status: -19
[ 4001.567897] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x0 status: -19
[ 4001.568103] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 4001.572366] cp210x ttyUSB1: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[ 4013.647342] usb 3-1.4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 4013.650435] usb 3-1.4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

Please suggest me what went wrong.

Comment: Hi, after  adding your public key to the ~/.ssh/authorized_key file on the dev board, did you try connecting with ssh mendel@192.168.101.2?

Comment: Hi, actually ssh works now. I fixed the permission for .ssh folder and authorized_key and now I can connect via ssh but mdt still does not work. I have edited my original post.

Comment: Seems like ssh is not working again. This is so strange, The same private-public key pair worked last day and now it shows the error: permission denied (public key) on the same PC. I have no idea.

Comment: This sounds very strange, just not normal linux behavior o_0
Definitely not something I've seen before so it very hard to diagnose. Could you try a different USB-A to USB-C cable and/or re-flashing the board?

Comment: I tried both and still no luck. I could connect via ssh user@IP just once after I flushed coral board. The next  attempt to connect via ssh does not work! It gives me permission denied (publickey). I have no clue what is happening. I will make another question about it with details and add the link here.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this also upgrading to "day".  There are several ways to skin this cat but the trick to use mdt is to put the generated private key at ~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key, which must be where mdt is hardcoded to look for it.

So for mdt and ssh access I did this:

1) use ssh-keygen to create private and pub key files.

2) append (or copy) the pubkey file to target /home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys

3) copy the private key file to ~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key

4) add to local .ssh/config to something like this:

```
Host tpu
         IdentityFile ~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key
         IdentitiesOnly=yes
         User mendel
```

Comment: I do not have config file inside .ssh folder in my local PC. I am running ubuntu 19.04. Is it possible that it is in another directory? Or should I create config file?

Comment: You should create a *config* file in `$HOME/.ssh`; it really helps to define and configure SSH sessions.  See man:ssh_config.

Comment: I followed all the steps, but still cannot connect via 'mdt shell'. It gives the following:

Connecting to 192.168.101.2 at 192.168.101.2
Couldn't establish ssh connection to device: Could not deserialize key data.

Any ideas?

Comment: More surprises: I flushed coral board and could connect via ssh user@IP just for once. The next  attempt to connect via ssh does not work! It gives me permission denied (publickey). I have no clue what is happening. I will make another question about it with details and add the link here.

Comment: I don't know what is going on with your setup.  For MDT, some ideas: review the coralboard setup instructions entirely, and follow each.  Make sure you do the udev setup for `65-edgetup-board.rules` and add yourself to udev group (and re-login!)  Generate the mdt.key and mdt.key.pub files using man:ssh-keygen.  Use coralboard serial console to login to coralboard (recommended screen terminal) and copy or cut-and-paste pubkey into */home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys* file.  Make sure authorized_keys file is `chmod 600`, otherwise ssh reports a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

I could connect via mendel development tool to coral dev board from freshly installed ubuntu. Also the ip changed from 192.168.101.2 to 192.168.100.2 on running `mdt shell`.

procedure:

1. Install mendel development tool on linux host PC
2. Connect coral dev board via serial port, power on and login to board
3. run `mdt devices` on host PC to see if dev board is already connected (should output 192.168.100.2)4. shell from host PC terminal
4. run `mdt shell`

If coral board needs to be connected to another host PC, only `mdt shell` will give some errors, I believe it's because it cannot append keys to authorized_keys folder.

1. One option is to login to dev board via serial port (inside the screen terminal of the dev board), do `cd ~/.ssh/` and remove authorized keys file by `rm authorized_keys`. Then move to host PC(ubuntu) terminal and run `mdt shell` from host PC terminal
2. Or manually generate ssh private-public keys, replace or append(did not test) content of authorized_keys file by the generated public key from host PC (should be in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file in host PC).

Answer (score 0):

I could connect via mendel development tool to coral dev board from freshly installed Ubuntu.

Procedure:

1. Install mendel development tool on linux host PC
2. Connect coral dev board via serial port, power on and login to board
3. Run `mdt devices` on host PC to see if dev board is already connected (should output 192.168.100.2)4. shell from host PC terminal
4. Run `mdt shell`

If coral board needs to be connected to another host PC, only mdt shell will give some errors, I believe it's because it cannot append keys to authorized_keys folder.

---

- One option is to login to dev board via serial port (follow this link to enter Screen/Serial Console https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/serial-console/#connect-over-usb-otg). Inside the screen terminal of the dev board, do `cd ~/.ssh/` and remove authorized keys file by `rm authorized_keys`.
- Then move to host PC(ubuntu) terminal and run `mdt shell` again from host PC terminal and this will create keys automatically and then let you into the board.

---