# Google coral dev board: ssh connects first time, for every next attempt it shows permission denied(publickey)

Tags: ssh, file-permissions, permission-denied, ubuntu-19.04, google-coral

I have a google coral board manufactured on 1st February, 2019. I flushed the board with the latest Mendel Enterprise Day 4.0. I am using Ubuntu 19.04 desktop and tried to connect to the board via google's recommended Mendel Development Tool using `mdt shell` (mdt documentation here: https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/mdt/), but it does not work (I have a separate question for that here:[Cannot connect to coral dev board after updating to 4.0: mdt shell does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325078/cannot-connect-to-coral-dev-board-after-updating-to-4-0-mdt-shell-does-not-work), please answer if you can)

So I decided to use ssh and followed these sequantial steps:

1. I already had ssh private and public key generated in my Ubuntu desktop
2. I logged in to the board via serial port (screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200), created $HOME/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys with proper permission and copy pasted public key from local $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file to authorized_keys
3. I tried ssh user@IP from terminal and it gave me the following error:

   > @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
   >   WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
   >   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
   >   IT IS
   >   POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! Someone could be
   >   eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also
   >   possible that a host key has just been changed. The fingerprint for
   >   the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
   >   SHA256:hotsxb/qVi1/ycUU2wXF6mfGH++Yk7WYZv0r+tIhg4I. Please contact
   >   your system administrator. Add correct host key in
   >   /Users/scott/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message. Offending
   >   ECDSA key in /Users/scott/.ssh/known_hosts:2 ECDSA host key for
   >   192.168.101.2 has changed and you have
   >   requested strict checking. Host key verification failed.
4. I fixed this problem by running `ssh-keygen -R 192.168.101.2` from terminal
5. Then I was able to connect to coral board via ssh user@IP
6. Next, I tried to do `scp` from another terminal to copy a folder and it gave me some permission error, or just did not work (I do not remember exactly). So I thought I should change the permission of mendel folder to allow read, write and execute. So, I set permission for $HOME/mendel as `sudo chmod -R a+rwx mendel`
7. After this point, I cannot connect via ssh and get `permission denied(publickey)`
8. I actually now remember that .ssh file is inside `$HOME/mendel` directory, so changing permission for that dir has actually changed permissions for `/.ssh` and `authorized_keys`. So I changed permission for `.ssh` as 700 and `authorized_keys` as 600, with `sudo`. However, `ssh user@IP` still does not work.

Please help me if you know how this can be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

## Follow steps to create key

connect your coral dev board using OTG then in your system terminal do

ssh-keygen

mdt pushkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

ssh mendel@192.168.100.2

Answer (score 0):

I have not really solved it i.e. could not figure out how to go back to the default permissions of $HOME of the coral board. Eventually, I have flushed the board again and this time I did not make the mistake to change permission of $HOME folder (like in #6 in the question) in coral board. Also, scp worked fine this time.
Lesson learned: be very careful to change permission of directories!